# ICMP Ping Request/Reply

Tags: ping, icmp

I try to ping something out with a PC/Router IP address 10.57.1.2 with the following Ping Request and Ping Reply received

Ping Request
Source      10.57.1.2
Destination 192.168.31.10

Reply
source      10.32.103.3
Destination 10.57.1.2

Will the PC/Router be treated a successful ping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a success if that's what you're expecting.  All command-line ping programs I've seen will display where the replies have come from.  If you send a braodcast ping you will often get multiple replies, and the ping program will display them.

Pingers that are built into network equipment may behave differently, in particular if you are pinging for a load-balancer liveness test then you'll have to check your particular load-balancer to see if the different source is accepted.

Comment: Yes. It is actually what i am expecting. For Cisco Switch, it treated that as a successful ping. For PC, it doesn't